# Comparação de Strings

Tags: php, string, validação

Existem várias formas de comparação, porém sempre vejo que as mais indicadas são (`===, strcmp ou strcasecmp`).

Entre essas formas apresentadas consideradas as mais seguras (segundo alguns sites na internet), seguem as dúvidas:

1. Qual seria a mais indicada para utilização?
2. Qual a diferença entre elas?
3. Existe também alguma diferença em performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Estás a referir aproximações diferentes. Se bem que ambas comparam duas strings o que retornam (ou dizem acerca das strings) é diferente.

`===` retorna somente um Booleano, true ou false.

[`strcmp`](http://php.net/strcmp) retorna negativo (`<0`) se a primeira string passada à funcão fôr menor que a segunda; positivo caso contrário; e zero se forem iguais.

Pode dizer-se que `===` é para saber se são idênticas, e `strcmp` é para comparar strings retornando 3 possibilidades.
`strcasecmp` é uma variante de `strcmp` mas *case-insensitive*, ignorando se tem letras grandes ou pequenas.

#### Performance:

Só é possivel comparar diferencas de performance no caso que ambos têm em commun, ou seja quendo se quer comparar se duas string são idênticas.

Assim, tendo em conta que `strcmp` e `strcasecmp` precisam de mais uma verificação  para saber o resultado fica óbvio que `===` é mais rápido. Ou sejam strcmp corre primeiro `strcmp(strA, strB)` e depois têm de ter mais uma verificação de igualdade `== 0`. [Encontrei entretanto alguns numeros aqui](http://maettig.com/code/php/php-performance-benchmarks.php) que apontam para performance 3x mais rápida usando `===`.

#### Conclusão:

Se o que se pretende é saber se duas strings são idênticas deve usar-se `===`.

Comment: Você sabe se existe alguma diferença de performance entre elas?

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft juntei mais info na resposta.

Answer (score -5):

Use === se quiser saber se são idênticas.

Se quiser saber qual é a maior de qual user strcmp.

Não fique só nesse post vá sempre mais longe que puder em conhecimento.