# Como distinguir FALSE da string vazia?

Tags: php

Várias funções do PHP (e.g. [SplFileObject::fgets](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/splfileobject.fgets.php)) retornam `FALSE` em caso de erro (e.g. fim de arquivo), mas também podem retornar uma string vazia (neste exemplo, se o arquivo tiver uma linha vazia); é impossível distinguir os dois casos com o teste ingênuo

```
$line = $file->fgets();
if ($line) { /* errado! */ }
```

Qual o jeito menos prolixo de detectar um erro numa chamada de função dessas?

Comment: Relatado: [Comparação de Strings](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56738/3635)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use o operador triplo `!==` ou `===`:

```
if ($line !== FALSE) { /* Correto */ }
```

Os operadores duplos `==` e `!=` compara apenas o valor em si, já os operadores triplos `!==` e `===` compara também o tipo do dado.

Exemplos de uso:

```
// String
""     ==  FALSE -> Verdadeiro
""     === FALSE -> Falso
"algo" ==  TRUE  -> Verdadeiro
"algo" === TRUE  -> Falso

""     !=  FALSE -> Falso
""     !== FALSE -> Verdadeiro
"algo" !=  TRUE  -> Falso
"algo" !== TRUE  -> Verdadeiro

// Array
[]     ==  FALSE -> Verdadeiro
[]     === FALSE -> Falso 
['oi'] ==  TRUE  -> Verdadeiro
['oi'] === TRUE  -> Falso 

[]     !=  FALSE -> Falso
[]     !== FALSE -> Verdadeiro 
['oi'] !=  TRUE  -> Falso
['oi'] !== TRUE  -> Verdadeiro 

// Número
0 ==  FALSE -> Verdadeiro
0 === FALSE -> Falso
1 ==  TRUE  -> Verdadeiro
1 === TRUE  -> Falso

0 !=  FALSE -> Falso
0 !== FALSE -> Verdadeiro
1 !=  TRUE  -> Falso
1 !== TRUE  -> Verdadeiro

//Tipagens diferente
'0' == 0    -> Verdadeiro
'0' === 0   -> Falso
'1' == 1    -> Verdadeiro
'1' === 1   -> Falso

'0' != 0    -> Falso
'0' !== 0   -> Verdadeiro
'1' != 1    -> Falso
'1' !== 1   -> Verdadeiro
```

**Atenção:** O uso do `if` e do `while` sem operação lógica, ou seja:

```
if ($line)
while($line)
```

É o mesmo que usar o operador duplo `==`:

```
if ($line == TRUE)
while($line == true)
```

**Atenção²:**

Algumas funções retornam valores verdadeiros mas que são interpretados como falso pelo operador simples, como é o caso da função [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php), por exemplo:

```
if (strpos('algo', 'a')) -> Falso (Aqui o retorno é 0, e este valor é interpretado como false pelo operador simples)
if (strpos('algo', 'a') !== FALSE) -> Verdadeiro
```

Descrito na [documentação da função `strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php):

> **Aviso**
>   Esta função pode retornar o booleano **FALSE**, mas também pode retornar um valor não-booleano que pode ser avaliado como **FALSE**, como `0` ou `""`. Leia a seção em [Booleanos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.boolean.php) para maiores informações. Utilize o operador [===](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php) para testar o valor retornado por esta função.

Para mais informações sobre operadores do PHP consulte a [Documentação Online](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Faz diferença escrever `FALSE` ou `false`?

Comment: Opa @ctgPi, não faz não. Eu gosto assim, mas você pode escrever da forma que achar melhor... ;)