# Qual o mais rápido is_null($y) ou $y == null?

Tags: php

Qual o mais rápido `is_null($y)` ou `$y == null`?

Comment: Particularmente, em alguns casos, preocupar com microotimização é desnecessário. É como uma frase que eu vi por aí a fora "... alguns programadores descobrem que o `for` é um milionéssimo de segundo mais rápido para iterar com array do que o `foreach` e monta uma palestra falando que não devemos usar `foreach`..."

Comment: @WallaceMaxters existem casos que é o contrario, ao menos nos últimos testes que fiz de micro-optimização `foreach` foi mais rápido.

Comment: PauloCosta é provável que a diferença seja impercepitivel, no entanto eu prefiro usar `$y === null` (com três sinais de `=`), pois a comparação é estrita.

Comment: No geral, @GuilhermeNascimento, a regra que eu uso é a seguinte: "começou com ===, então agora tem que ir no sistema todo. Feio é ter uma parte de um jeito e outra, de outro".

Comment: @WallaceMaxters exato, se a comparação pode ser estrita, por que não faze-la no sistema todo? Com um sublimetext da vida e uma consulta por regex você encontra todos locais que necessita editar.

Comment: Alguma das respostas lhe ajudou? Ou há problemas nelas? Comente informando ao autor qual a duvida em tentar usar a solução proposta. Se alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema, marque-a como correta clicando em ✓

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Segurança das Expressões

A pergunta que realmente deve-se fazer é a seguinte, "**Qual é mais seguro de se usar?**". Por exemplo, as expressões a seguir:

```
"oi" == null    => false
""   == null    => true
0    == null    => true
null == null    => true

is_null("oi")   => false
is_null("")     => false
is_null(0)      => false
is_null(null)   => true

"oi" === null   => false
""   === null   => false
0    === null   => false
null === null   => true
```

#### Otimização

A diferença entre `===` e `is_null` é praticamente irrelevante, a não ser que você tenha cerca de dois milhões de expressões como essa em um *script* para necessitar de uma otimização significativa.

[Um dos comentários na documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php#84161) diz o seguinte (em tradução livre):

> Micro otimização não vale a pena.
>
> Você tinha que fazê-lo dez milhões de vezes a notar uma diferença, um pouco mais de 2 segundos
>
> `$a===NULL;` Durou: 1,2424390316s
>
> `is_null($a);` Durou: 3,70693397522s
>
> Diferença = 2,46449494362s
>
> Difereça/10.000.000 = 0,000000246449494362ns
>
> O tempo de execução entre `=== NULL` e `is_null` é menos do que **250 nanosegundos**. Vá otimizar algo que valha a pena.

<sub>[Obs.: Fiz alguns testes e os vários resultados não passaram de 100 nanosegundos, e a média de diferença fica entre 20 ~ 50 nanosegundos.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/17dfa0ada922b502d33ac8df9ba62e7cb59c626f)</sub>

#### Conclusão

Se deseja realmente otimizar e ter segurança no seu código, dê preferencia à comparação com o operador triplo:

```
$y === null
```

Porém não vale a pena ficar vasculhando o código procurando otimizar essas expressões (a não ser que procure pelo operador simples `==`). Pois a diferença é tão insignificante, que o tempo seria melhor investido caso estivesse limpando/melhorando o código ou estudando.

Mais detalhes sobre expressões lógicas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69576/8493

Mais detalhes sobre operadores lógicos: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 6):

Tudo depende do que você quer verificar, não deve ser olhado somente a performance. Por exemplo:

```
<?php

$str1 = "";
$str2 = null;
$str3 = 0;

var_dump(is_null($str1)); // retorna false
var_dump(is_null($str2)); // retorna true
var_dump(is_null($str3)); // retorna false

var_dump($str1 == null); // retorna true
var_dump($str2 == null); // retorna true
var_dump($str3 == null); // retorna true

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

A sua pergunta tem rasteira porque o resultado nunca é o mesmo para:

```
is_null($y) ou $y == null
```

para comparar deve de o fazer sobre:

```
is_null($y) ou $y === null
```

Aqui sim os resultados serão semelhantes. É importante referir que tem situações onde a aplicabilidade do operador `===` é impossível. Em casos que seja necessário utilizar em callbacks apenas o `is_null` pode ser utilizado.

***Numa resposta directa à pergunta no que respeita à performance:***
A diferença não é relevante.

**Mas:**
Ambas são abordagens diferenciadas para o mesmo problema.

**Porque...**

1. is_null é uma função que no caso do PHP é executa um C. Em resultado é obtida alguma latência.
2. No caso do *PHP* a diferença é mínima porque por se tratar de uma linguagem de script baseada em *C* a interpretação do código `$y === null` irá na mesma sempre originar chamadas de métodos *C* em qualquer um dos casos.

**Opinião:**
Eu aplico de acordo com a situação, mas escolheria sempre $y === null pois é um operador base e por esse motivo nuclear... pelo que o *PHP* tende a resolver com menos esforço certamente.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe nenhuma diferença entre `is_null` and `=== null`.
A unifica diferença e que `is_null` se trata de uma função e por consequencia,

1° A chamada da função faz ela ficar mais lenta,  mas isso falanto de um tempo relativamente insignificante.

2°  Por se tratar de uma função você pode usa-lá de callback, exemplo:

```
  array_map('is_null', $array);
```

Na documentação do php existe um teste de  benchmarking com 10 milhões de iterações que  acaba concluindo  da seguinte forma,  a comparação de uma variável com um operador é muito mais rápido, então não use `is_null` a menos que precise de um callback.

[Php - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php#84161)

Comment: +1 . A função `is_null`, embora por ser uma função é mais lenta que uma expressão (não é um construtor da linguagem, mas é uma função mesmo), é excelente usá-la como callback. Ela poderia ser usada em `array_map`, `array_filter` e afins :)

Answer (score -1):

**$y == null**.

Em questão de performance não é tão relevante a diferença, porém se usado com frequência, realmente vale mais apena usa-lo.

Comment: Por quê ele é mais rápido? Se puder melhorar sua resposta, ela certamente irá ajudar mais pessoas que, assim como eu, não entendem nada de php.