# Operador de comparação ou isset()?

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para loterias, onde cada jogo gerado passa por `N` filtros antes dos números serem mostrados.
As dezenas são escolhidas, passadas via `$_POST` para um arquivo php que fará o restante.

Nele eu possuía um código basicamente assim:

```
foreach ($jogos_gerados as $jogos) {
    if ($_POST['filtro_1'] == 'on') {
        // Procedimentos do filtro
    }
    if ($_POST['filtro_2'] == 'on') {
        // Procedimentos do filtro
    }
    // E assim se repetia por mais 120 filtros
}
```

Pois bem, acontece que para o tratamento de aproximadamente 150 mil apostas eu estava tendo um tempo de processamento muito grande, mesmo quando eu não estava ativando os filtros `$_POST['filtro_X'] == 'off'`. Eis que então resolvi trocar tudo desta forma:

```
foreach ($jogos_gerados as $jogos) {
    if (isset($_POST['filtro_1'])) {
        // Procedimentos do filtro
    }
    if (isset($_POST['filtro_2'])) {
        // Procedimentos do filtro
    }
    // E assim se repete por mais 120 filtros
}
```

E o tempo caiu drásticamente para < 5s. O que estou curioso em saber é porque essa diferença tão grande entre `isset()` e um operador de comparação. Sendo que em minha visão, tanto um quanto outro tem que ser verificado se existe para entrar no filtro (`TRUE` para `isset()` e `ON` para o operador de comparação).

Comment: Você não ficou nenhum pouco curioso se existe alguma forma de você evitar ter que fazer mais de 100 `ifs`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu sei que eu poderia fazer de outras formas, mas eu só estou curioso em entender o que aconteceu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função¹ `isset()` e a comparação de valores são coisas distintas, fazem coisas distintas e seu uso não é exclusivo entre si. O `isset()` verifica se uma variável está definida no escopo atual, retornando verdadeiro quando está, independente do valor; já o operador `==` compara o valor da variável e não se ela está definida. De fato, o operador `==` até gera um erro quando a variável não estiver definida.

Ou seja, você utiliza `isset()` quando deseja verificar se uma variável está definida e o operador `==` para verificar o valor. No geral, os dois são utilizados concomitantemente, pois antes de verificar o valor você deve verificar se ele está definido.

Apenas para ressaltar meu comentário, se você precisa fazer mais de 100 verificações no seu programa, é um bom sinal que você irá precisar refatorá-lo. Aparentemente você está mandando os valores dos filtros como *on* ou *off* e isso não faz muito sentido. Você poderia enviar pela requisição apenas os filtros que estão ativos e assim percorrer a lista normalmente em `$_POST` com o `foreach`. Se esta requisição está vindo do HTML, esses campos possivelmente deveriam ser `checkbox`, não `radio` ou qualquer outro.

Não irei comentar sobre a diferença de tempos de execução entre ambas porque não faz sentido comparar coisas distintas.

<sub>[1] O `isset()` na verdade é um construtor de linguagem, não uma função e, para o PHP, há considerações a serem feitas.</sub>

Comment: Entendi, obrigado Anderson!

Answer (score 4):

O `isset` é apenas para checar se um variável ou chave existe dentro de um array ou `stdObject`, é importante notar que se a variável tiver o valor `NULL` também irá retornar false, então conforme exemplos:

```php
<?php
$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
$baz = null;

var_dump(isset($foo)); //Retorna true
var_dump(isset($bar)); //Retorna true
var_dump(isset($baz)); // Retorna false
var_dump(isset($naodeclarada)); // Retorna false
```

Exemplo de uso com um array:

```php
<?php
$foo = array(
    'bar' => array(
        'baz' => 1
    )
);

var_dump(isset($foo['bar']['baz'])); //Retorna true
var_dump(isset($foo['bar']['baz']['teste'])); //Retorna false
```

Seria semelhante com `stdClass`:

```php
<?php
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->baz = new stdClass;
$foo->baz->bar = 1;

var_dump(isset($foo->baz->bar)); //Retorna true
var_dump(isset($foo->baz->bar->teste)); //Retorna false
```

É importante notar também que `isset` pode ser usado para checar múltiplos valores ao mesmo tempo:

```php
if (isset($_POST['foo'], $_POST['baz'], $_POST['bar'])) {
    //Executa
}
```

Seria o mesmo que:

```php
if (isset($_POST['foo']) && isset($_POST['baz']) && isset($_POST['bar'])) {
    //Executa
}
```

Note que **variáveis** em PHP com valor tipo *string* podem funcionar semelhante a arrays, por exemplo:

```php
$foo = 'abc';

var_dump($foo[0]); //Irá exibir "a"
var_dump($foo[1]); //Irá exibir "b"
var_dump($foo[2]); //Irá exibir "c"
```

Ou seja para checar se uma variável tem conteúdo, geralmente usamos `!empty(...)`, que ficaria assim:

```php
if (!empty($_POST['foo']) && !empty($_POST['baz']) && !empty($_POST['bar'])) {
    //Executa
}
```

Que diferente do `isset` irá checar se a variável é vazia, no entanto você pode conseguir fazer assim:

```php
if (isset($_POST['foo'][0], $_POST['baz'][0], $_POST['bar'][0])) {
    //Executa
}
```

O que facilitaria bem mais, mas é claro que é importante notar que `empty` faz bem mais do que checar strings vazias, para ele considerar uma variável como vazia ela poderá conter os seguintes tipos de valores:

- `""` (uma string vazia)
- `0` (quando for um numero inteiro igual a zero)
- `"0"` (zero como string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (uma array vazia)
- `public $var;` (Quando uma variável é declarada em uma classe, mas não tem valor, pois é NULL)

Como expliquei em [**Qual é a diferença na verificação de um array com isset e array_key_exists?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117504/3635), ou seja o `empty` pode ter mais usos além do que o `isset` será capaz, use ambos conforme a necessidade.

Agora sobre comparar com `==` é importante notar que se não tiver `isset` ou `empty` para checar antes provavelmente se o `error_reporting` no `php.ini` estiver configurado com `E_NOTICE` ou `E_ALL` ele irá emitir mensagens (**que não são erros**) se estiver em uma pasta com `GET` (ou qualquer tipo que não for POST) tentar fazer isto:

```php
<?php
if ($_POST['foo']) {

}
```

Ou:

```php
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
```

Vai ser exibido a seguinte mensagem:

> Notice: Undefined index: foo in pagina.php

A mensagem quer dizer que a superglobal POST existe, mas o `index` (se refere a chave) chamada `foo` não existe.

Então para o seu código especifico talvez o ideal seria algo assim:

```php
foreach ($jogos_gerados as $jogos) {
    //Checa se tem no mínimo 2 caracteres e se é "on" em "filtro_1"
    if (isset($_POST['filtro_1'][1]) && $_POST['filtro_1'] == 'on') {
        // Procedimentos do filtro
    }

    //Checa se tem no mínimo 2 caracteres e se é "on" em "filtro_2"
    if (isset($_POST['filtro_2'][1]) && $_POST['filtro_2'] == 'on') {
        // Procedimentos do filtro
    }
}
```

No entanto estando dentro de um loop, que é o `foreach`, acho que múltiplas checagens são desnecessárias, você poderia otimizar a performance e até a escrita, poderia fazer algo como:

```php
function getFilters()
{
     $filters = array();

     //O 200 aqui é a quantidade possível de filtros que você terá, pode editar
     for ($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++) {
        $key = 'filtro_' . $i;

        //Faz uma comparação "inline" e salva no array
        $filters[$i] = isset($_POST[$key][2]) && $_POST[$key] == 'on';
     }

     return $filters; //Retorna o array
}

//Pega os filtros
$filtros = getFilters(); //Irá retornar algo como array( 1 => true, 2 => false, ...)

foreach ($jogos_gerados as $jogos) {
    //Não precisará de isset, pois existe, só que é false ou true dependo do valor de filtro_1
    if ($filtro[1]) {
        // Procedimentos do filtro
    }

    //Não precisará de isset, pois existe, só que é false ou true dependo do valor de filtro_2
    if ($filtro[2]) {
        // Procedimentos do filtro
    }
}
```

Comment: porque você utilizou `=== 'on'` em getFilters() em vez de `== 'on'`? O resultado não seria o mesmo?

Comment: @thiago força do habito, é que === compara o tipo e acabo sempre fazendo uso dele, institivamente, mas para o seu caso não é muito necessário, apesar de ser razoavelmente mais performatico (mas só se tiver uns 1000 loops pra notar algo diferente)

Comment: @thiago [O que é uma comparação frouxa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215652/5878)

Comment: @thiago um exemplo sobre o uso de ===, ==, !== e !===: [Como distinguir FALSE da string vazia?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69576/3635)

Comment: Entendi, parecem besteiras mas são detalhes importantes. Obrigado pelas explicações @AndersonCarlosWoss e Guilherme!

Comment: @Thiago sim, é importante entender como as strings se comportam, vc terá muitos beneficios. Uma pergunta, chegou a testar a função `getFilters` que criei? Qualquer problema me avisa.

Answer (score 2):

O [isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) retorna um valor booleano, *true* ou *false*, ou seja, verifica se a variável existe ou não.

Verificar se a variável tem um valor definido com `==` é mais trabalhoso ao servidor, pois, além de receber o POST, deverá verificar se o seu valor é o esperado. No `isset()`, o servidor executa apenas 1 passo, *true* ou *false*.

A sensível melhora de performance na sua aplicação se dá porque o PHP não precisa verificar se o valor é "on", "off" ou qualquer coisa.

Comment: Entendo, de qualquer forma irei tentar otimizar minha aplicação. Obrigado @dvd!

Comment: @thiago Obrigado!!